# How to get facebook offline_access token?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

How to get offline access token of facebook? 
I know that from recently time is out of date. And  if I can't get offline access tokens. 
What solutions of this problem is?

Comment: What exactly do you need it for? In 99% `offline_access` token is an overkill

Comment: I do not want to every time when token is ended, window pops up which asking "PLEASE LOG IN AGAIN"

Comment: you don't need to. And that's why I asked: "What **exactly** do you need it for?"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a fresh token, simply follow [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/). You can obtain it through the JavaScript SDK, or doing a request to Oauth. In both cases the user will not notice anything unless he de-authenticated your app.

Comment: In the same link you provided him, just on the top of the page it has a very clear notice saying: "Please note: On May 2, 2012, the offline_access permission will be removed". If you don't know the answer, what's the point in answering? Are you trying to confuse him or just waste his time?

Comment: No need to attack. I am sorry, I misread the question, thought he was asking for a normal access token. Anyway, as the comment said, it might be an overkill. I will edit or delete my answer in a minute.

Comment: As the OP added a new comment where he explained what he wants, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Laky: unfortunately he didn't explain what he wants, he just explained how he wants to solve it (in a wrong way). We still don't see the original issue

Comment: Alright, sorry, sometimes I see people who are just trying to somehow gain more reputation by answering the little they know. zerkms, I'm with Laky on this one, seems like he just wanted the offline_access so that he won't have to deal with tokens expiration. The link in his edited answer is probably right.

Comment: I agree the question is quite vague, but from what he said it seems like the issue is that he always wants to have a fresh token without bothering the user. Unless he gives more detail, I think that pointing him to the part of manual which deals with this problem is the best answer we can give.

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer: 1. be more polite please. 2. to do **everything** you want - you don't need offline_access, that's why it is deprecated. You can do whatever you want with temporary tokens. And to know that you just need to read some documentation and have some practice. At least my applications work perfectly without user interactions and without offline_access. Is it magic? Nope, it is rtfm ;-)

Comment: @Laky: "he always wants to have a fresh token without bothering the user" -- so? You can retrieve fresh tokens and do whatever you want without bothering the user. That is why I said that he has described wrong solution, not a real issue.